# How to set java environment variables using shell script

Tags: linux

I know I can just type 
`$ vi .bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

However how to use shell script to do it? I prefer to write shell script because I need to configure multiple servers, if type one by one I would take me a long time to go.

Can someone guide me how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends on how many servers you need to update and what type of infrastructure is already in place.  How many servers?

Comment: You could (potentially) `scp` the `.bashrc` to all of the servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just realized that you wanted a script to automate the process of adding environment variables. These commands may work for you:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" >>~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" >>~/.bashrc
```

What this does is append the given text to `.bashrc`. Instead of copying `.bashrc` files from server to server, run these commands (you could probably write a script for these) on each server. This preserves the contents of the original rc files on each server, which I find is a better idea than completely overwriting the file.

**Original answer**

Your `.bashrc` file is actually written as a shell script. You would place the exact same lines in the shell script, possibly with a hashbang at the beginning of the file. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# do java stuff here...
```

If you were to "do java stuff" in this script, this would work fine. However, if these variables are going to be used outside of the script, you would have to "source" this file. That is what happens with `.bashrc`. Before the first prompt is given, Bash runs `source ~/.bashrc` to publish the variables defined in `.bashrc`.